# What port ranges does vsftpd use when in active mode and connect_from_port_20 is default (no)?

Tags: linux, port, vsftpd

I am attempting to ascertain the range of ports that vsftpd will use for my particular configuration. As I mentioned above the mode is active and connect_from_port_20 is default (I believe this is "no").
A packet trace consistently shows the control port appears to be dynamic (49152-65535) for client source and tcp21 for server destination. The data port however is destination client (control port source +1) and server source range seems to be 1024-65535 (this is a guess as I can't see any other pattern or boundaries.) However, I cannot find any documentation to support what I am seeing definitively. So, can you all please shed light on the ambiguity here? If you can verify or correct my assumptions that would be most helpful and fill in any gaps that you see missing I would be grateful. 
Thanks in advance.